# What's the most efficient way of deleting multiple records from a MySQL server?

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net

I'm writing a C# winforms program as practice with MySQL to track my pretend employees in a pretend company. My Data Grid View gets the records straight from the MySQL server. My question is, what's a more efficient way to delete employees by Employee_ID?

I was thinking about using either a foreach statement that sends a delete query to the SQL server for each row that's selected, or somehow do a bulk query that deletes all the rows where the employee_id matches. I'm not too sure how either would look. I'm still new to MySQL.

I appreciate the help, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can delete multiple records with a single DELETE statement by using `IN`:

```
DELETE FROM yourtable
WHERE Employee_ID IN (1, 45, 47, ... )
```

Comment: How would I delete from a list of objects? Say I have a list of selected rows?